# Stopping threads started by @Async in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, completable-future

I am having an async method .

```
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Void> getRandom(){
     // Return null or some exception is thrown
     // I will be calling restTemplate.getForEntity() here
     // So I can get some correct response or I can get HttpClientErrorException or HttpServerErrorException
    }
```

This is being called in following way : -

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>() ;

for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    futures.add(commonUtil.getRandom());
 }
   
   for(CompletableFuture<Void> future : futures){
  try{
    future.get();
  }catch ( ExecutionException ex){

    Throwable ee = ex.getCause() ;
    if(ee instanceof CustomException){
    
       CustomException exception = (CustomException) ee ;
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

       throw exception ;
```

So as I am calling Async method inside loop , so whenever I get the customexception from any one of them , I want to kill all other treads which was triggered inside the loop and send this exception to the ***Controller*** ( as I want it to send to the client ) .

How can I do that ?

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: You don't. Also you shouldn't be calling `get` on each and every completable future but rather `join` all of them in 1 single `CompletableFuture` and then call the `handle` method, which either gives you the result else the exception. Everything else will be handled for you then.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer showing code ?

Comment: @M.Deinum , Can I know what exception has been thrown by different threads ? Or will `join` stop everything else if exception is thrown by one thread ? Can you please elaborate on it as I am a beginner in this ?